# Django filter does not filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm trying to filter my API results through url parameters, but it's not working as expected. what am I missing in my code? even on DateRangeFilter, it's not filtering. Thanks!

```
class RainfallFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    start_date = DateFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr=('gt'))
    end_date = DateFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr=('lt'))
    date_range = DateRangeFilter(field_name='timestamp')

    class Meta:
        model = Rainfall
        fields = ('level', 'amount', 'timestamp')


class RainfallView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RainfallSerializer
    queryset = Rainfall.objects.all()
    filterset_class = RainfallFilter

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = RainfallSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `get` method as you override above is missing filtering. It should be:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = RainfallSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```